# Question from Peter Petersen

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm trying do a exercise from Peter Petersen's book, but I don't know what do.
Well, assume that

> $$R=\frac{scal}{2n(n-1)}g\circ g+\left(Ric-\frac{scal}{n}g\right)\circ g+W$$

Where, R is the Riemannian curvature tensor, scal is the scalar curvature, W is the Weyl tensor, and we define the Kulkarni-Nomizu product of two (0,2)-tensor as a (0,4)-tensor:

> $$h\circ k(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)=h(v_1,v_3)\cdot k(v_2,v_4)+h(v_2,v_4)\cdot k(v_1,v_3)-h(v_1,v_4)\cdot k(v_2,v_3)-h(v_2,v_3)\cdot k(v_1,v_4)$$

I know that this decomposition is orthogonal, in particular

> $$|R|^2=\left|\frac{scal}{2n(n-1)}g\circ g\right|^2+\left|\left(Ric-\frac{scal}{n}g\right)\circ g\right|^2+|W|^2$$

I know that the curvature operator $\mathcal{R}:\Lambda^2TM\to\Lambda^2TM$ has the fllowing block decomposition:

> $$\mathcal{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
>  A&D \\ 
>  B&C 
> \end{bmatrix}$$

where, $A,C$ are symmetrics and $D=B^*$

What I don't know is the following:

> In dimension 4, show that
>   $$|R|^2-\left|Ric-\frac{scal}{4}g\right|^2=tr(A^2-2BB^*+C^2)$$

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In decomposition of $R$, I think that $\frac{1}{n-2}$ is missed in front of $Ric - \frac{s}{n}g$

Comment: I did it, later I'll put answer here

Comment: Could you put tne answer here please?